# ASP.Net WebForms Application Hosted on Windows Server 2019. Missing ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, scriptresource.axd

I tried to migrate an ASP.Net app from WS 2012 R2 to WS 2019. Since .Net Framework 4.8 is included in WS 2019, I compile the app in .NEt Framwork 4.8 from VS and deploy it to IIS 10 on WS2019. Everythink works fine when I connect in localhost from server but from other device I have the error '__doPostBack is not defined'.

When I compare sources loaded by browser from 'localhost' and 'other devices'. I notice that in localhost 3 files ScriptResource.axd are included in the page + 1 WebResource.axd BUT from other device, only 2   ScriptResource.axd  are included and no  WebResource.axd. I'm sure that '_doPostBack' definition is in the missing ScriptResource file. There is no 404 error, the script tag are just missing at the body begining.

Does someone know why there is a difference in included scripts beetween localhost and external connection ? It's important to note that external connection pass through AWS ALB and WAF.

Thank you

Regards

Comment: An MVC application does not use PostBack and ScriptResource, those are from Webforms. Are you sure you are not mixing technologies?

Comment: You're right, It's ASP WebForms. I updated the post

Comment: Enable verbose error messages and logging in the application and in IIS to see if any errors or warnings are generated when external devices access the site. And check the web.config or IIS settings for any URL rewrite rules that may affect the script file path.

Comment: As you said at the end, when accessing the ASP.NET application from external devices via AWS ALB and WAF, some script files are missing. AWS WAF can be configured to block or filter certain requests based on predefined rules or custom rules. Check your AWS WAF configuration to make sure it is not blocking the request responsible for loading the missing script file.

Comment: I found the solution ! The problem was in the request, not the response. AWS routing process changed the User Agent Header to a value not handled by IIS. So IIS do not generate all the needed scripts. After aws routing process keep the original request header for User Agent, everything is working fine.

Comment: That’s great! If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, post an answer yourself describing the solution and then accept that, which will also help others to solve a similar issue.